# Unable to end session after logging out using passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

**I am using:**

```
"express": "^4.18.1",
"express-session": "^1.17.3",
"mongoose": "^6.4.0",
"mongoose-encryption": "^2.1.2",
"passport": "^0.6.0",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
"passport-local-mongoose": "^7.1.2"
```

**In my app.js file:**

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true },
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", { useNewUrlParser: true });

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

app.get("/profile", function (req, res) {
  User.find({ email: { $ne: null } }, function (err, foundUsers) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      if (foundUsers) {
        res.render("profile", { foundUsersEjs: foundUsers });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**Now, I have tried these two ways to get a POST request for logout:**

1. Method one

```
app.post("/logout", function (req, res) {
  req.logout(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      req.session.destroy(function (err) {
        res.redirect("/");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

2. Method two

```
app.post("/logout", function (req, res) {
  req.session.destroy(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      req.logout(function (err) {
        res.redirect("/");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

**In my ejs file:**

```
<form action="/logout" method="post">
    <button class="btn btn-light btn-lg">Log Out</button>
</form>
```

The issue is that when I click on the logout button *(using any of the two methods mentioned above)* inside the profile page `http://localhost:4100/profile`, I am redirected to the home route `"/"` thinking that I actually logged out.

When I manually append `/profile` in my link on the home page `http://localhost:4100` after logging out, I am still able to view the profile page. Does it mean the session isn't ended when I clicked on the logout button or is it something else and what is the solution?

Comment: Please share code of `/profile` route

Comment: added code of  `/profile` route in my app.js code block.